# Getting a percentage of float without digits before decimal point

Tags: c#

What is the best approach to convert floats like so:

```
0.433432 -> 0.43
0.672919 -> 0.67
3.826342 -> 0.82
6.783643 -> 0.78
```

i have a float array and want to convert all the values it contains
Thanks :)

Comment: tried anything?

Comment: you could cast your original value to int and minus the result with the original, then print it with with two decimal place

Comment: You don't know how to do this in C# or you don't know how to this at all? If your logic is not clear then even C# can't help you..

Comment: What does this have to do with percentages?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, have you attempted this yourself yet? do you have any example code of your attempts at getting your desired result?

Comment: That was more like a logic question, i added c# because i try to do this with c# Max Play and Dmitry Bychenko gave a pretty good answer and i feel kinda dumb, cause their answers seem pretty logical. if i didnt try anything why would i ask tho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get *fractional* part and *truncate* it up to *two digits*. If values are *positive* and *small* you can implement it like this:

```
 private static double Solution(double value) {
    return (long)((value - (long)value) * 100) / 100.0;
 }
```

Test:

```
 double[] test = new double[] {
   0.433432,
   0.672919,
   3.826342,
   6.783643, };

 var result = test
   .Select(item => $"{item} -> {Solution(item)}")
   .ToArray();

 Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
 0.433432 -> 0.43
 0.672919 -> 0.67
 3.826342 -> 0.82
 6.783643 -> 0.78
```

**Edit:** What's going on in the `Solution` method:

- `value - (long) value`  - integer part removing
- `(long) ((...) * 100)`  - scaling up and truncate
- `() / 100.0`            - scaling down back

If we have, say, `1234.5789` these three stages will be:

- `0.5789` - integer part removing
- `57`     - scale up and truncate
- `0.57` - scaling down back

Comment: Thank you that will do it. Altough i have floats but thats a minor change

Comment: I think its worth clarifying more precisely what you mean by small (and indeed clarifying why positive is a requirement)? I assume its that `(long)value` may overflow in the case of the size. For positive I'm not sure - is it just a case of not wanting to define expected behaviour for negative numbers? If I do `Solution(-1.41421)` I get `-0.41` which is what I would probably expect so it seems like positive isn't really required...

Answer (score 0):

You could subtract the integer value.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    array[i] -= ((int)array[i]);
```

Comment: Well that seems pretty plausible. Facepalm ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
value = Math.Truncate(100 * value) / 100;
```

OR

```
decimal result = TruncateDecimal(0.433432, 2);
```

Comment: What is `TruncateDecimal`? It looks like it must be a method in your class from how it is being called but you've not shown us the code...

Comment: Also this doesnt work you still have to get rid of the digits before the decimal point. So it display 0.xx

Comment: Please have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer to provide more detail. Specifically, it would be helpful if you explained how this solves the problem